# Sorting of footable column of integers rendering unexpected results due to string sort

Tags: jquery, sorting, asp.net-mvc-4, footable

I am using footable.js plugin to sort a table in my MVC application. On clicking the row header for a column containing integers values they are being sorted as follows:

```
81, 811, 776, 700, 70
```

Is there anything I can do to this library that would enable the sorting of integer columns to be sorted on value:

```
811,776,700,81, 70
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: data-type="numeric" added to column sorted this

Comment: Add this as an answer, then in a couple of days accept your answer. It'd help other people with the same problem if they see that your question was answered, even if it was by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

data-type="numeric" added to column sorted this

Answer (score 1):

In newer releases, *data-type="number"* will do it.